# Clear input when selecting radio button

Tags: input, radio-button, append, toggle

I have two radio buttons to append and remove a div (see code snippet)

Now, **I need to** clear the input-text when you change from one button to other.

For example, if you have selected "One" and type "name", when you select "Two", the input-text should be reset to blank (and viceversa)

How do I do this?

```js
$(function(){

  let content=[
    '<div class="added"> HELLO </div>',
    '<div class="added"> BYE </div>'
  ];
  let toggled=0;
    
$("[name='something']").on('change', function(){
    $(".added").remove();
    toggled=(toggled+1)%2;
    $(".toadd").append(content[toggled])
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
  
  <label>One</label><input type="radio" class="first" name="something" checked />
  <label>Two</label><input type="radio" class="second" name="something" />
  
  <input type='text' class='toclear'>
  
  <div class="added"> HELLO </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.val('')` you can make an input blank:

```js
$(function(){

  let content=[
    '<div class="added"> HELLO </div>',
    '<div class="added"> BYE </div>'
  ];
  let toggled=0;
    
$("[name='something']").on('change', function(){
    $(".added").remove();
    toggled=(toggled+1)%2;
    $(".toadd").append(content[toggled])
    $(".toclear").val('');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
  
  <label>One</label><input type="radio" class="first" name="something" checked />
  <label>Two</label><input type="radio" class="second" name="something" />
  
  <input type='text' class='toclear'>
  
  <div class="added"> HELLO </div>
  
</div>
```